# how do you style data frame and write to excel in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, pandas-styles

I need to change the background's color of the dataframe headers to orange:

My `df` looks like this:

```
Campus    Server      Port
AZ       server12    Eth1
AZ1      server12    Eth2
AZ2      server23    Gi2
NV       Server34    Eth2
```

I tried this:

```
df1=df.style.set_table_style(
[{
   'selector': 'th',
   'props':  [('background-color', '#FFA500')]
}])
```

When I try to write this `df1` to Excel, I don't see the color of the header's background changing:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('C:/documements') as writer:
  df1.to_excel(writer, index=False
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the CSS styles (*if not all*) applied with [`set_table_styles`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_table_styles.html) won't export to Excel (*see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html#Methods-to-Add-Styles)*).

You could use [`apply_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply_index.html#), instead :

```
bg = ["background-color: #FFA500"]*len(df.columns)

st = df.style.apply_index(lambda _: bg, axis=1)

st.to_excel("output.xlsx", index=False)
```

Preview (*output.xlsx*) :

[image]

Comment: I am getting AttributeError: 'Styler' oject has no attribute 'apply_index'

Comment: FYI, this code works for me.

Comment: Thanks Corralien ;), I just *re-checked* and seems like @user1471980 are using a version older than [`1.4.0`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#styler).